# Parallel downloads from S3 with Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some very large files on s3. I want to download them using the ruby sdk.

Is there a way of downloading them in parallel?

I could use the ’parallel’ gem but wondering if there was another way eg native functionality built into the sdk

Sequential downloads takes a long time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Threads`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Thread.html) which are part of the Ruby core like this:

```
downloads = []

downloads << Thread.new { # download file 1 }
downloads << Thread.new { # download file 2 }
#...
downloads << Thread.new { # download file n }

# Ensure that all threads finished their work before moving on
downloads.each(&:join)
```